# Deleting Worksheets if range is blank

Tags: vba, excel

I made a code that would delete Worksheets if range **"D14:K70"** is empty throughout the workbook but I do not know how to ignore "-----------" which are in the worksheet range **72x** and empty spaces are **368x**. Also I am having an issue at **Sheets(i).Delete**

```
Sub DeletingEmptyPages()

Dim i As Long

For i = Sheets.count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(i).Range("D14:K70"), "") >= 368 Then
        If Sheets.count > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Only 1 sheet left"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: use `CountA` instead

Comment: @ShaiRado I did, CountA deletes all sheets

Comment: Have you tried IsEmpty instead?  You could combine it with a Replace for "-".

Comment: @Liss Can you demonstrate what you mean by that.

Comment: Your range is **456** cells............are some of them **completely empty** or do they contain formulas that can **return Empty**??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent my range is 440 cells, within this range there are cells that are completely empty and some have numbers but all of the worksheets have 72 cells which have "-----------"

Comment: I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DeletingEmptyPages()

Dim i As Long

For i = Sheets.count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(i).Range("D14:K25, D27:K27, D29:K31, D34:K34, D36:K52, D55:K55, D57:K57, D59:K66, D68:K68, D70:K70 "), "") >= 368 Then
        If Sheets.count > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Only 1 sheet left"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way of approaching the same issue. You could add in a do whole loop to stop if it find something as it will speed up the process slightly but the range is so small I don't think it will be an issue.

```
Sub DeletingEmptyPages()

Dim i As Long
Dim strTestRange As String
Dim bDeleteSheet As Boolean

strTestRange = "D14:K70"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    bDeleteSheet = True
    For Each c In ws.Range(strTestRange)
        If Not (c.Value = "" Or c.Value = "-") Then bDeleteSheet = False
    Next c

    If bDeleteSheet Then
        If Sheets.Count > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Only 1 sheet left"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```